# Typescript no overload matches this call

Tags: node.js, typescript, express, passport.js

I'm new to TypeScript and I'm currently stuck. I have a nodejs and express app.

I'm getting the following error: No overload matches this call.

```
The last overload gave the following error.
    Argument of type '{ isLoggedIn: (req: Request<ParamsDictionary, any, any, QueryString.ParsedQs, Record<string, any>>, res: Response<any, Record<string, any>>, next: NextFunction) => Response<...> | undefined; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'RequestHandlerParams<ParamsDictionary, any, any, ParsedQs, Record<string, any>>'.
      Type '{ isLoggedIn: (req: Request<ParamsDictionary, any, any, ParsedQs, Record<string, any>>, res: Response<any, Record<string, any>>, next: NextFunction) => Response<...> | undefined; }' is missing the following properties from type '(ErrorRequestHandler<ParamsDictionary, any, any, ParsedQs, Record<string, any>> | RequestHandler<ParamsDictionary, any, any, ParsedQs, Record<...>>)[]': length, pop,
```

### This is my route file

```
export {}

import express, { Router } from 'express';

import lessons from '@controllers/lessons';
import isLoggedIn from '@middleware/user';

const lessonRoutes: Router = express.Router();


lessonRoutes.route('/')
        .get(isLoggedIn, lessons.lessonForm)
```

---

This is my middleware file

```
import { Request, Response, NextFunction } from 'express';

const isLoggedIn = (req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => {
    if (!req.isAuthenticated()) {
        return res.status(401).json({
            error: "User must sign in"
          })
    }
    next();
}

export default {
    isLoggedIn
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your exports from the middleware file have been set up incorrectly.

You are constructing an object with one property, `isLoggedIn`, which is the handler function, and then exporting that object as the default export.

So, when you import the default export from this file in the line:

```
import isLoggedIn from '@middleware/user';
```

Now `isLoggedIn` is equal to the value of the default export. i.e. `isLoggedIn` is an object with one property `isLoggedIn` that is equal to the handler function. So, instead of passing a function to `route('/').get(...)` like it expects, you are passing it an object.

You can use a named export from your middleware file instead:

```
export const isLoggedIn = (...) => ...;
```

Then import it by name:

```
import {isLoggedIn} from '@middleware/user';
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `as any` type assertion to turn off type checking for get parameters.
https://bobbyhadz.com/blog/typescript-no-overload-matches-this-call

```
lessonRoutes.route('/')
    .get(isLoggedIn as any, lessons.lessonForm)
```